# display mysql results into table

Tags: php, mysql

I want to show my mysql table into a table in my page. Everything works but the order is reverse, the first line is 20, then 19, 18, 17 and so on. Can someone help me?

```
      <?php
$id = mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("angajati", $id) or die('Could not select db: ' . mysql_error());
$query1 = "SELECT * FROM angajati ";
$result = mysql_query($query1) or die('Error querying database.');

echo "<table summary='text' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0'>
<thead>
<tr>
<th>ID</th>
<th>Nume</th>
<th>Prenume</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody> 
";

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result) )
{
echo "<tr class='dark'>";
echo "<td>" . $row['ID'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['Nume'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['Prenume'] . "</td>";
}
echo "</tbody> </table>";
mysql_close();
?>
```

Comment: close the `tr` tag in the `loop`

Comment: **Stop** using deprecated `mysql_*`API. use `mysqli_*` or `PDO`

Comment: As i do understand you correctly, you should order your result: `SELECT * FROM angajati order by ID ASC`

Answer (score 1):

1) use order by ID asc

```
`SELECT * FROM angajati order by ID asc`
```

2) Missing tr close

> Warning mysql_query, mysql_fetch_array,mysql_connect etc.. extensions were deprecated in PHP 5.5.0, and it was removed in PHP 7.0.0.
>   Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used.

Try to use mysqli_*

```
          <?php
        $id = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","") or die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_connect_error());
        mysqli_select_db( $id,"angajati") or die('Could not select db: ' . mysqli_error());

        $query1 = "SELECT * FROM angajati order by ID ASC";

        $stmt =  $id->prepare($query1);
        $stmt->execute();
        $result = $stmt->get_result();
        $count = $result->num_rows;

        echo "<table summary='text' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0'>
        <thead>
        <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Nume</th>
        <th>Prenume</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody> 
        ";
        if($count>0){
            while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
            {
            echo "<tr class='dark'>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['ID'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['Nume'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['Prenume'] . "</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
            }
        }
        echo "</tbody> </table>";
        mysqli_close($id);
        ?>
```

Comment: if my answer is useful mark it with green tick it's useful for future user reference . @MelnicIvan